# How to manage couple of shops with Business central

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

We're not sure how to manage couple of shopify shops with business central.
We've separate URL's for Separate shops and separate products but one business central account.
Any documentation for help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple `Shopify Shops` in the same company within Business Central.

Each `Shopify Shop` has its own URL and you can specify which `Locations` should be included in the inventory calculation of each `Shopify Shop`.

A good starting point in setting up the Shopify Connector is probably the [offical walkthrough from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/shopify/walkthrough-setting-up-and-using-shopify).

In the walkthrough you will also find a description of how to [sync specific items to a specific shop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/shopify/walkthrough-setting-up-and-using-shopify#steps).

Comment: Thanks Kasper. We can manage locations that is great, but what I want to understand is when we click on shopify tab after installing shopify connector in business central, we always see data i.e. products, customers, orders from the first enabled shop.

Is there any way we can toggle data b/w different shops or filter data, right now we're deleting the other shop in order to check the synching??

Comment: The walkthrough explains how to sync specific items to a specific shop. I have added a link in my answer.